# iOS build issue With Xcode (10.2)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.2

My Xcode Version is 10.2 and MacOS Version is 10.14.4.

I am new to iOS. I have a project in Unity, which I export and build in Xcode. If I build my project with Xcode-9.4 it works perfectly. But When I try to build my project with XCode-10.2 it gives me this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>     Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/FE30DBA8-091A-4350-9E8F-2CAF3FF03497/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libBluetooth.framework/libBluetooth
>     Reason: image not found

I have google it a lot but found nothing helpful any help is highly appreciated.

Below are the solutions I have already tried.

1. Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries => Yes (Not helpful)
2. "Clean" my project (shift+cmd+K) a
3. My Apple World Wide Certificate is already valid.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me :

- Close **Xcode**
- Open **Keychain Access**
- Right click on your certificate -> **Get Info**
- Under **Trust** -> Change **When using this certificate** value to **Use System Default**